# Creating functions in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL, so please try not to be overly critical about my question,  I need to create a function which would return me a  table (say for example "machine") , which would have a column called "aggtablename"  and the rows would be filled with values derived from a database. Here is what i tried and the following error came....so please help me in making my syntax correct, THANKS..

```
CREATE FUNCTION aggtable() RETURNS TABLE (machineid, serveraggtablename)
AS $table$  
BEGIN     
  RETURN QUERY    
  SELECT m.machineid, m.serveraggtablename   
  FROM machine m 
   END; 
 $table$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;  

select aggtable();
```

> ERROR:  function aggtable() does not exist LINE 1: select aggtable();
>                  ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TYPE machineType as (machineid int, serveraggtable character varying);

CREATE FUNCTION aggtable() RETURNS SETOF machineType AS 
'SELECT m.machineid, m.serveraggtablename FROM machine m;' 
LANGUAGE 'sql';

SELECT * FROM aggtable();
```

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions

Comment: Thanks for your help
but, now there is one more issue, i changed the  syntax...now the error i am getting is : 

CREATE TYPE machineType as (machineid int, serveraggtable character varying);

CREATE FUNCTION aggtable() RETURNS SETOF machineType AS 
$$
BEGIN
  SELECT id, serveraggtablename 
  FROM machine ;
END;
$$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT * FROM aggtable();

ERROR:  query has no destination for result data

Comment: @user3688338 That is another question. If this answer solved the posted question then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of the table you're returning do not have any type.

try adding a type such as machineid int.

check this post

[How can a Postgres Stored Function return a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329247/how-can-a-postgres-stored-function-return-a-table)

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged, please post some code and explain